# How to plot a numpy array with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I generate a circle numpy array like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

a, b = 3, 3
n = 7
r = 3
arr = np.ones((n, n))
y, x = np.ogrid[-a:n-a, -b:n-b]
mask = x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= r**2
arr = 255 * mask.astype(int)

print(arr)
```

it print result like this:

```
[[  0   0   0 255   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255 255   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0 255 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0   0   0 255   0   0   0]]
```

I want to plot this numpy array? How can I do this?

---

EDIT

What I want to show is a circle, not the default picture:

[image: plt.imgshow show this]

Comment: please specify what you want more clearly. 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(arr)
plt.show()
Will answer your question, but probably isn't what you need

Comment: @Chrisvdberge I want to show a circle, I have tried `plt.imgshow`, but it seems not a circle.

Comment: still not clear what it exactly is that you need; do you need to plot the numpy array you created or is this just your way of trying to plot the circle? Will the array contain different values (different colors in the circle?) or do you simply want a circle?

Comment: Heavily increase `n` (and maybe adapt the other parameters, too) to see something actually more circle-shaped. At the moment, you have some very "undersampled" circle.

Comment: The plotting script is doing what you want, only your sample size is too small.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [matplotlib's color map feature.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors


a, b = 3, 3
n = 7
r = 3
arr = np.ones((n, n))
y, x = np.ogrid[-a:n-a, -b:n-b]
mask = x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= r**2
arr = 255 * mask.astype(int)


cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['purple', 'yellow'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image]